# filter list and show results on text entry in angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a div controller with a div having initialized with an array inside the controller using `ng-init` .I need to show the filtered objects inside this array using a text from textbox as a filter. Also I need the objects to be displayed when user types in the input. This is my base code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
<div style="display:none" ng-init="CustList=[
{custid:1,custname:'Raj Export House1',address:'Plot.No.123, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
{custid:2,custname:'Vinay Export House2',address:'Plot.No.567, Industrial Area, New Delhi 201301'},
{custid:3,custname:'Maya Export House3',address:'Plot.No.777, Industrial Area, Faridabad 201301'},
{custid:4,custname:'Devat Export House4',address:'Plot.No.425, Industrial Area, Gurgaon201301'},
{custid:5,custname:'Yespal Export House5',address:'Plot.No.153, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
{custid:6,custname:'Abhinav Export House6',address:'Plot.No.1423, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
{custid:7,custname:'Surya Export House7',address:'Plot.No.1253, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
{custid:8,custname:'Lalata Export House8',address:'Plot.No.12553, Industrial Area, Gurgaon 201301'},
{custid:9,custname:'Raj Export House9',address:'Plot.No.12553, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
{custid:10,custname:'Manu Export House10',address:'Plot.No.15823, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'}]"></div>
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="txtSearch" ng-change="CallSearch(txtSearch)">
<ul>
  <li style="display:none" ng-repeat="cust in CustList | filter:txtSearch">
    {{ cust.custid + '   ' + cust.custname + '   ' + cust.address + ',' }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.CallSearch = function(textSearch)
{
    if(textSearch.length>0);
    $("li").css("display","block");
}
});
</script>
```

I also tried using `ng-repeat="cust in CustListfunction()` and defined this function inside scope

```
      $scope.CustListfunction=function(){
      var result=[];
      angular.forEach($scope.CustList, function (item) {
      if($scope.textSearch.length>0)
        {
          result.push(item);
         }
        });
      return result;
      }
```

But it didnt get me anywhere, is there anything I am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround I figured,and it is close to what I needed :

```
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div  style="height:100px">

</div>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
<div  ng-init="CustList=[
{custid:1,custname:' Export House1',address:'Plot.No.123, Industrial Area, Pune 200180'},
{custid:2,custname:'Vi Export House2',address:'Plot.No.567, Industrial Area, New Delhi 201301'},
{custid:3,custname:'May Export House3',address:'Plot.No.777, Industrial Area, Faridabad 201301'},
{custid:4,custname:'Dev Export House4',address:'Plot.No.425, Industrial Area, Mumbai 60021'},
{custid:5,custname:'Yes Export House5',address:'Plot.No.153, Industrial Area, Pune 200180'},
{custid:6,custname:'nav Export House6',address:'Plot.No.1423, Industrial Area, Pune 200180'},
{custid:7,custname:' Export House7',address:'Plot.No.1253, Industrial Area, Pune 200180'},
{custid:8,custname:'Lat Export House8',address:'Plot.No.12553, Industrial Area, Mumbai 201301'},
{custid:9,custname:' Export House9',address:'Plot.No.12553, Industrial Area, Pune 200180'},
{custid:10,custname:'Man Export House10',address:'Plot.No.15823, Industrial Area, Pune 200180'}]"></div>
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="txtSearch" ng-change="CallSearch(txtSearch)">
<ul>
  <li ng-show='myVar' class="filterlist"  ng-repeat="cust in CustList | filter:txtSearch">
    {{ cust.custid + '   ' + cust.custname + '   ' + cust.address + ',' }}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.myVar=false;
$scope.CallSearch = function(textSearch)
{

    if(textSearch.length>0);
    {
      $scope.myVar=!$scope.myVar;


    }

}
});
</script>
```

Just used ng-show,could have used ng-disabled too.Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you probably want:

```
<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="txtSearch">
    <ul>
      <li ng-if="txtSearch" ng-repeat="cust in CustList | filter:txtSearch">
        {{ cust.custid + '   ' + cust.custname + '   ' + cust.address + ',' }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

results will be displayed only if search criteria was entered.
also, as was already said here, move your list to the controller:

```
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.CustList = [
    {custid: 1, custname: 'Raj Export House1', address: 'Plot.No.123, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
    {custid: 2, custname: 'Vinay Export House2', address: 'Plot.No.567, Industrial Area, New Delhi 201301'},
    {custid: 3, custname: 'Maya Export House3', address: 'Plot.No.777, Industrial Area, Faridabad 201301'},
    {custid: 4, custname: 'Devat Export House4', address: 'Plot.No.425, Industrial Area, Gurgaon201301'},
    {custid: 5, custname: 'Yespal Export House5', address: 'Plot.No.153, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
    {custid: 6, custname: 'Abhinav Export House6', address: 'Plot.No.1423, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
    {custid: 7, custname: 'Surya Export House7', address: 'Plot.No.1253, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
    {custid: 8, custname: 'Lalata Export House8', address: 'Plot.No.12553, Industrial Area, Gurgaon 201301'},
    {custid: 9, custname: 'Raj Export House9', address: 'Plot.No.12553, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'},
    {custid: 10, custname: 'Manu Export House10', address: 'Plot.No.15823, Industrial Area, Noida 201301'}
  ]
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/H5lY8lXDivCnKYfogRll?p=preview

Comment: Thx ,I already have this solution but additionally I want the customer details to only show when user enters something in the textbox. So the page should be just with a textbox when it loads.

Comment: just add ng-if="txtSearch"  to your li element, I updated my answer and plunker

Comment: Thx for your answer it works. Is there any workaround which could involve `<input type="text" ng-model="txtSearch" ng-change="funcName(txtSearch)">` and then checking txtSearch.length to achieve the same,please suggest

Comment: it is absolutely redundant in your case, because angular filter does this functionality, but see my plunker, I added second search field, which uses ng-change, then I removed filter from ng-repeat and added track by ..., so angular won't add $$hashKey

Answer (score 0):

- Comment `$scope.CustListfunction` if still in use, don't need it
- Declare `$scope.txtSearch`
- Put `console.log('')` inside CallSearch  to see if it's hitting it properly.
- Remove `style="display:none"` to see if things are actually working. Make your appearance changes after
- I probably would not have `ng-init` my array like that, put it inside the `$scope.CustList= [.....]` in the script. Not sure if the current setup even works..

Hope this helps narrow down your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, working on them and will re-edit my code.Working on $scope.textSearch might work.earlier i could actually get all objects from array on textchange but it could not show on the screen.